# Setting slowmode for all channels in discord.js with one command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I made a command called ?lock1 which implements lockdown level 1 which is to put slowmode of 15 seconds in all channels of a server. Here is my code:

```
if(command == "lock1"){
      if(message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')){
        const embedlock1 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Lockdown level 1 implemented in this server")
        .setDescription('All channels in this server have a 15 second slowmode now')
        .setFooter("Lockdown Level 1")
        message.channel.send(embedlock1).then(message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channels => channels.setRateLimitPerUser(15,'lockdown lvl1')))
      }
    }
```

My bot is in 24 server and the command is only working in 1 server, if I use it in another server then I get an error saying `channels.setRateLimitPerUser` is not a function... please help me thank you

Answer (score 1):

`message.guild.channels.cache.forEach()` Will also return `category` type, as well as `voice` type which doesn't have `setRateLimitPerUser()`.
So, filter them out and take only `text` type channels.

```js
if(command == "lock1"){
  if(message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')){
    const embedlock1 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Lockdown level 1 implemented in this server")
      .setDescription('All channels in this server have a 15 second slowmode now')
      .setFooter("Lockdown Level 1")
    message.channel.send(embedlock1).then(message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channels => {
      if (channels.type === 'text') {
        channels.setRateLimitPerUser(15,'lockdown lvl1')))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need try this:

```js
if(command == "lock1"){
  if(message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')){
    const embedlock1 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Lockdown level 1 implemented in this server")
      .setDescription('All channels in this server have a 15 second slowmode now')
      .setFooter("Lockdown Level 1")
    message.channel.send(embedlock1).then(msg => {
    message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channels => {
      if (channels.type === 'text') {
        channels.setRateLimitPerUser(15,'lockdown lvl1')))
                                    }
                                                     }
                      }
                                                  }
                                          )
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.